# Analyzing sound from microphone on Android (harmonics, partials, overtones)

Tags: java, android, audio, fft

I want to develop an Android app that analyzes sound input (a note played on a piano) from the microphone and analyzes it so that I end up knowing the frequency and amplitude of all prominent partials (the fundamental tone and the overtones).

Can someone point me in the right direction, an algorithm, working code, an article etc.

Apparently, asking if there already is an existing library for this is off topic, weirdly. So I won't ask that.

Comment: I don't understand why my question is off topic. How can it be off topic on SO to ask how to solve a programming problem? I don't care if the answer is an algorithm, a library, an article, working code etc., just something that will point me in the right direction so that I can solve the problem at hand. Not different from any other programmer question I or anyone else have asked before.

Comment: We really like specific reproducible questions with a sample of code, expected results, and the results you are getting, or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Also, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721254/how-to-calculate-sound-frequency-in-android

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is spectrum estimation, which is often done using a FFT algorithm. Google spectrum estimation and you should find the info you are after.